# Is there a method to perform a derivative by inbuilt function in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-3.5, standard-library

I don't want to use numpy because it isn't permitted in competitive programming.I want to take derivative of for instance m=a(a**2-24a).
Now,a=0 and a=8 are critical points. I want to find this value.Is it possible by using any python library function excluding numpy.

Comment: There is no "derivative" implementation in the standard library. You can, of course, *implement your own*.

Comment: Why are you posting this in the comments of this question? If you have another question, start another question.

Comment: Oh sorry I am new over here hence didn't knew. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m=a(a**2-24a)` does not make sense as a Python expression, regardless of what `a` is.  The first `a(` implies a function; `a**` implies a number, and `24a` is I-don't-know-what.

Derivative is a mathematical concept that's implemented in `sympy` (symbolic math).  `numpy` also implements it for polynomials.  `numpy` also implements a finite difference approximation for arrays.

For a list of numbers (or two lists) you could calculate a finite difference approximation (without `numpy`).

But for a general function, there isn't a derivative method for Python nor `numpy`.

Your question might make more sense if you give examples of the function or lists that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the implementation in the [numpy repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) and use that information to implement your own version. You should start with [polyder](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f751336b0261fb86b15f949251f31314e08ecc00/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L442). Probably you do not need half of the code in their implementation.